# JavaScript Validation for Listbox when mulitple values are selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox, listbox

I want to do JavaScript validation for listbox

If Value from Lisbox is not selected, it should get alert "Please Select Your Skill"

But if user select 3 Skill from 6 Skill. I need that 3 skiils should get alert using JavaScript.

Here is my Code...

call script on submit button..

```js
<html>
    <head>
        
    <script></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <form name="registration" id="registration_form_id" action="" method="post">
            
             <select id="skillid1" name="skill[]" multiple="multiple" size="3" >
                    
             <option value="html">HTML</option>
             <option value="css">CSS</option>
             <option value="javascript">JAVASCRIPT</option>
             <option value="php">PHP</option>
             <option value="mysql">MY-SQL</option>
             <option value="jquery">JQUERY</option>
             
             </select>
             
            <button type="submit" onClick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
            
        </form>
     </body>
    
</html>
```

Thank you
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use `onsubmit` form event instead of button click. In this case you return false when the form should not be submitted. Here is an example:

```js
function myFunction(form) {
    
    var select = form['skill[]'];

    // Check if skill is selected
    if (select.selectedIndex === -1) {
        alert("Please Select Your Skill");
        return false;
    }
    
    // Check if selected 3 skills out of 6
    if (select.selectedOptions.length) {
        var options = [].map.call(select.selectedOptions, function(option) {
            return option.text;
        }).join('\n');
        alert("You selected: \n" + options);
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="registration" id="registration_form_id" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction(this)">
    <select id="skillid1" name="skill[]" multiple="multiple" size="3">
        <option value="html">HTML</option>
        <option value="css">CSS</option>
        <option value="javascript">JAVASCRIPT</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="mysql">MY-SQL</option>
        <option value="jquery">JQUERY</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note that returning true from event handler will submit the form (in above demo submission is suppressed).

Here is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fea9gzk/) demo.

Comment: *selectedOptions* is pretty new (isn't it?). Do you know of support (e.g. it's not supported in OmniWeb 5.11 or IE 10 apparently)?

Comment: @RobG One can simply loop over `options` collection and get `selected` options.

Comment: Sure. For mixing NodeLists with native methods I prefer a simple *toArray* function, then call the native method on that without *call* or *apply*, e.g. `toArray(select.options).filter(function(option){return option.selected})`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected options from a multiple select, you should iterate over the [*options* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-options) and collect the ones that are selected.

There is also the [*selectedOptions* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-selectedoptions) (per dfsq's answer), but support is patchy across browsers.

The looping method is made easier with a simple *toArray* function:

```
// Return an array of list members in numeric index order
// Respect sparse lists.
function toArray(list) {
  var array = [];

  // Use for loop for maximum compatibility
  for (var i=0, iLen=list.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // Respect sparse lists
    if (list.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      array[i] = list[i];
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

So if you have a reference to the select element, you can get the selected options using:

```
var selectedOptions = toArray(select.options).filter(function(option) {
                        return option.selected;
                      });
```

Now you can show the displayed text of each option in an alert using:

```
alert(selectedOptions.map(function(option){return option.text}).join('\n'));
```